# How to check upper case existence length in a string - Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to check upper case existence length in a string using Sql Query?

For Eg:

1.KKart - from this string the result should be 2, because it has 2 upper case letters.
2.WPOaaa - from this string the result should be 3, because it has 3 upper case letters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As i have mentioned in the request, SQL QUERY ?

Comment: can anybody help me with this query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in T-SQL function for that.
You can use a user-defined function like this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CountUpperCase
(
    @input nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    declare @len int
    declare @i int
    declare @count int
    declare @ascii int

    set @len = len(@input)
    set @i = 1
    set @count = 0

    while @i <= @len
    begin

        set @ascii = ascii(substring(@input, @i, 1))

        if @ascii >= 65 and @ascii <= 90
        begin
            set @count = @count +1
        end

        set @i = @i + 1

    end

    return @count

END
```

Usage (with the examples from your question):

`select dbo.CountUpperCase('KKart')` returns `2`.
`select dbo.CountUpperCase('WPOaaa')` returns `3`.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this :

```
SELECT len(replace(my_string_field,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','')) as 'UpperLen'
FROM my_table
```

The principle is simply to replace all lower case char by nothing and counts the remaining.

Comment: Did you try to run this on the example strings in the question? Your code only replaces the whole string 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' if it occurs exactly like that. Plus, there can be stuff like numbers in the string which are not upper case or lower case characters at all.